# Web app with Azure AD SSO: Is it possible to give users from an external tenant access to their email?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, microsoft-graph-mail

I have an application registered in Azure Active Directory. I use this app registration to provide a simple SSO implementation for my web application. Users go to my application, choose SSO for authentication, redirect to the login.microsoft.com page, then get sent back with the proper codes. No sweat.

The SSO part is not issue inside or outside of my tenant. I've been able to get the proper flow setup and if users are permitted access, they can login with their Microsoft account and access my application.

Email, however, is turning out to be a real issue.

Internal users in my tenant are not a problem at all. Once I get the JWT from Microsoft, I can request an access token for Graph, send emails, create drafts, delete, etc. There is no issue here.

The problem comes up when I have a user in an external tenant. They can login just fine and get a code from Microsoft, but email doesn't work. I started researching a multitenant solution with the Graph API and made some progress there. I was able to change how they request their tokens using 'client_credentials' and got the appropriate delegated app permissions set up but those permissions allow the external tenant to send emails as though they were users in my tenant. Which obviously I don't want.

I have the external users setup as guest users in my tenant. I've even gone so far as to put an Exchange Online license on the guest users account.

This is the latest error I've received:

```
[error] => Array
    (
        [code] => ResourceNotFound
        [message] => Resource could not be discovered.
        [innerError] => Array
            (
                [date] => 2021-08-09T16:08:41
                [request-id] => 76d9c8ad-e2fd-4286-a8d7-5a3bb4ff3ba8
                [client-request-id] => 76d9c8ad-e2fd-4286-a8d7-5a3bb4ff3ba8
            )

    )
```

I get this when I put the external user's object ID in the request for the sendMail method of the Graph API. If I put an internal user's object ID into that request, the external user can login, get a token, and send mail as that internal user just fine.

So my question is, is this even possible? Can a user in an external tenant login to my app using Azure AD SSO and also have access to send mail from their account within my application? If so, how far off base am I with my implementation?

Comment: Interesting one. In such scenario i would try the best practices (1) Check the token, validate its scope/permissions (2) Not sure in your scenario, you're using Azure AD B2C (not sure it suits your scenario) or B2B and try to simulate accessing multiple mailboxes (3) I would test the above approach first in POSTMAN, make sure it works (test the tokens, valid permissions, flow works correctly) before i do the coding (4) Enable exception handling, check the errors that you're getting (5) I see that you're using SSO & Graph, then consider using MSAL

Answer (score 0):

As it is a multi-tenant application that supports SSO for external users.

As per Dev's Comment,
Not sure in your scenario, you're using Azure AD B2C (not sure it suits your scenario) or B2B and try to simulate accessing multiple mailboxes

Identity Providers for External Identities

External Guest users with personal MS Account can redeem your B2B collaboration invitations.

During Self Service sign-up user flow, personal MSA can be added as one of the Identity Provider.

No Additional Configuration required to make this identity provider available for user flows.

**Email one-time passcode:** When redeeming an invitation or accessing a shared resource, a guest user can request a temporary code, which is sent to their email address. Then they enter this code to continue signing in.

Email one-time passcode feature authenticates B2B guest users when they can't be authenticated through other means.

When setting up a self-service sign-up user flow, you can add Email One-Time Passcode as one of the allowed identity providers.

[image]

Reference link:
Identity providers for External Identities - Azure AD | Microsoft Docs
B2B Collaboration - Understand user tokens in B2B collaboration - Azure AD | Microsoft Docs

Comment: This is a multi-tenant application that supports SSO for external users. The issue is multi-tenancy through the Graph API and the ability to successfully retrieve valid access tokens to use with it. There's a breakdown somewhere with issuing ID tokens on login. Something with that process needs to be changed so that those tokens can be used to retrieve access tokens.